# How many children (min, max) should a R-tree node have?

Tags: java, tree, r-tree

I have 500.000 unique 3D points, which I want to insert into a R-tree. The constructor of the R-tree accepts two parameters:

- the minimal number of children a node can have
- the maximal number of children a node can have

I've read on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) that: "... best performance has been experienced with a minimum fill of 30%–40% of the maximum number of entries."

What would be the optimal values for the two parameters then ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, what wikipedia states is:

```
minimum = approximately 0.3 * maximum to 0.4 * maximum
```

as for the maximum, this depends on your exact setup and implementation. In particular the dimensionality of your data set plays a huge role, but also the kind of queries you perform (think of the average number of points returned per query!) Therefore, the *cannot* be a general rule.

However, as R-trees are designed to be operated on disk, you should maybe choose the maximum value so that it optimally fills a **single block on disk** (8kb?)